# Critical point by Taylor polynomial?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Use the second-degree Taylor polynomial to determine if the point $(1,1)$ is a critical point.

$f(x,y)=xy-x-y-2\cos\left(x-y\right)$ around the point $(x,y)=(1,1)$

$$f_{x}=y+2\sin \left(x-y\right)-1\\
f_{xx}=2\cos \left(x-y\right)\\
f_{xy}=-2\cos \left(x-y\right)+1\\
f_{y}=x-2\sin \left(x-y\right)-1\\
f_{yy}=2\cos(x-y)\\
\ \\
f(1,1)=-3\\
f_{x}(1,1)=0\\
f_{xx}(1,1)=2\\
f_{xy}(1,1)=-1\\
f_{y}(1,1)=0\\
f_{yy}(1,1)=2\\
\ \\
-3+0(x-1)+0(y-1)+\frac{2}{2!}(x-1)^2+\frac{-1}{1!1!}(x-1)(y-1)+\frac{2}{2!}(y-1)^2=x^2-xy-x+y^2-y-2
$$

If a insert $(x,y)=(1,1)$ in $x^2-xy-x+y^2-y-2$ i get $=-3$.

How do i use the taylor polynomial to determine if $(1,1)$ is a critical point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to use the second degree Taylor polynomial in a sensible way to do this, but if you must, here it goes:

The 2nd degree Taylor polynomial of a scalar function expanded at $a$ is
$$T^2 f(x;a)=f(a)+\nabla f(a)\cdot (x-a)+\frac{1}{2}(x-a)^T\mathrm H f(a)(x-a),$$
where $\nabla f$ is the gradient and $\mathrm Hf$ is the Hessian. Now $f$ has a critical point at $a$ if $\nabla f(a)=0$, in other words, if the second degree Taylor polynomial reduces to
$$f(a)+(x-a)^T\mathrm Hf(a)(x-a).$$
But that's just a detour around simply calculating $\nabla f$, which is the actually important condition, which you have to do anyway to find the Taylor polynomial.

What you *can* do with the 2nd degree Taylor polynomial, though, is to determine the type of critical point: if the Hessian is positive [negative] definite, then we have a minimum [maximum], and if it is indefinite, then we have a saddle point. If it is semi-definite, then the second degree Taylor polynomial can't be used to find the type of critical point.